# DROP TABLE on a Child table getting blocked by a SELECT on the parent table in Postgres 9.5

Tags: postgresql, locking

I have a parent/child relationship between table T and T_CHILD. When I have an Active transaction SELECTING from the parent - T, and I try to drop the child table (T_CHILD), the DROP statement just hangs, as this session tries to get an Access Exclusivelock on both the parent and child tables.
1. Is this expected behavior?
2. Why should Postgres prevent a child table from being dropped, eventhough dropping the child table has no impact on the SELECT on the parent table?  Can you please explain this?

```
dev_sporuran=# \d+ t
                          Table "public.t"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description
--------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id     | integer | not null  | plain   |              |
Indexes:
    "t_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "t_child" CONSTRAINT "t_child_fk" FOREIGN KEY (t_id) REFERENCES t(id)

dev_sporuran=# \d+ t_child
                               Table "public.t_child"
 Column |         Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
--------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id     | integer               |           | plain    |              |
 t_id   | integer               |           | plain    |              |
 name   | character varying(10) |           | extended |              |
Foreign-key constraints:
    "t_child_fk" FOREIGN KEY (t_id) REFERENCES t(id)

***********26727 session starts a SELECT ********
dev_sporuran=# begin;
BEGIN
dev_sporuran=# select * from t;
 id
----
(0 rows)

*****26727 gets a shared lock for the SELECT on the table and the PK******
dev_sporuran=# select locktype,database,relation::regclass,transactionid,pid,mode,granted
from pg_locks where pid in (26727,26780) order by pid;
  locktype  | database | relation | transactionid |  pid  |      mode       | granted
------------+----------+----------+---------------+-------+-----------------+---------
 relation   | 19752133 | pg_locks |               | 26727 | AccessShareLock | t
 relation   | 19752133 | t_pkey   |               | 26727 | AccessShareLock | t
 relation   | 19752133 | t        |               | 26727 | AccessShareLock | t
 virtualxid |          |          |               | 26727 | ExclusiveLock   | t
(4 rows)


**************26827 tries to DROP the t_child table ************
dev_sporuran=# select pg_backend_pid();
 pg_backend_pid
----------------
          26867
(1 row)

dev_sporuran=# drop table t_child;


********* This just hangs;
Looking at pg_locks - 26867 requires not only an Access Exclusive lock on t_child, it also needs an Access Exclusive Lock on the parent table - T.  
 But it cannot get it, because 26727 has a Share lock on it thru the SELECT statement.  So it has to wait*****

dev_sporuran=# select locktype,virtualxid,relation::regclass,transactionid,pid,mode,granted
from pg_locks where pid in (26727,26867) and relation::regclass in ('t','t_pkey','t_child') order by pid;
 locktype | virtualxid | relation | transactionid |  pid  |        mode         | granted
----------+------------+----------+---------------+-------+---------------------+---------
 relation |            | t_pkey   |               | 26727 | AccessShareLock     | t
 relation |            | t        |               | 26727 | AccessShareLock     | t
 relation |            | t_child  |               | 26867 | AccessExclusiveLock | t
 relation |            | t        |               | 26867 | AccessExclusiveLock | f
(4 rows)
```

Thanks
Murali

Comment: Can someone help me with this?  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like something you could raise for discussion on pgsql-hackers. At a glance I don't see a good reason it shouldn't be `ExclusiveLock` not `AccessExclusiveLock`, so it'd still permit `SELECT`. But most table structure alterations require A.E.L.

Take a look at the ALTER TABLE lock strengths reduction patch for how complex this sort of thing can be.